# How can i parse very long JSon string in iOS without memory error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am new on iOS,I have webservice and i am tring to download 9000+ product info and i have a very long JSON string,so i got this error message when products download,

> malloc: *** mmap(size=1978368) failed (error code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I tried to download below 1000 product info and it is working very well. i think, it is memory problem.

This code is part of my project.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

if (temp!=nil && ![temp isEqual:@""]) {
    //basliklar arrayine ilgili tek haberin basligini aktariyoruz.
    //NSLog(@"TEMP=%@",temp);


    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[temp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];



    UrunAdi=[data valueForKey:@"UrunAdi"];
    UrunNo=[data valueForKey:@"UrunNo"];
    Koleksiyon=[data valueForKey:@"Koleksiyon"];
    Kompozisyon=[data valueForKey:@"Kompozisyon"];
    GrM=[data valueForKey:@"GrM"];
    URMID=[data valueForKey:@"URMID"];
    En=[data valueForKey:@"En"];
    IslemTipi=[data valueForKey:@"IslemTipi"];
    Dizim=[data valueForKey:@"Dizim"];
    KarteleKodu=[data valueForKey:@"KarteleKodu"];
    Siklik=[data valueForKey:@"Siklik"];
    Euro=[data valueForKey:@"Euro"];
    Dolar=[data valueForKey:@"Dolar"];
    Sterlin=[data valueForKey:@"Sterlin"];
    TL=[data valueForKey:@"TL"];

    [sharedManager  getNewDBConnection];

    if(![temp isEqualToString:@"false"]){

        sqlite3 *contactDB;


        NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: SQL]];

        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == YES)
        {
            const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
            {


                NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from tblKumasBilgi"];

                const char *sql_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];

                if(sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                   // NSLog (@"Delete UserData Succesful");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Delete UserData Fail");
                }
                //sqlite3_close(contactDB);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
            }
        }
    }


    if([temp isEqualToString:@"false"]){

         [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        NSString *warning = NSLocalizedString(@"Warning",nil);
        NSString *check=NSLocalizedString(@"Check Your User Info",nil);
        NSString *okay=NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil);

        UIAlertView *alertViewUser = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:warning
                                                            message:check
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:okay
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertViewUser show];
        alertViewUser.tag=1;
        flag=NO;

    }
    else{

                sqlite3 *contactDB;

                NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: SQL]];

                NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == YES)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < [UrunNo count]; i++) {



                NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO tblKumasBilgi (UrunAdi,UrunNo,Koleksiyon,Kompozisyon,Grm,URMID,En,IslemTipi,Dizim,KarteleKodu,Siklik,Euro,Dolar,Sterlin,TL) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')", [UrunAdi objectAtIndex:i], [UrunNo objectAtIndex:i], [Koleksiyon objectAtIndex:i], [Kompozisyon objectAtIndex:i], [GrM objectAtIndex:i], [URMID objectAtIndex:i], [En objectAtIndex:i], [IslemTipi objectAtIndex:i],[Dizim objectAtIndex:i],[KarteleKodu objectAtIndex:i], [Siklik objectAtIndex:i],[Euro objectAtIndex:i],[Dolar objectAtIndex:i],[Sterlin objectAtIndex:i], [TL objectAtIndex:i]];

                //NSLog(@"insert =%@",insertSQL);

            const char *sql_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            if(sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                //NSLog (@"INSERT INTO UserData Succesful");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"INSERT INTO UserData Fail");
            }

        }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database");
        }
        //sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }

        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        NSString *warning = NSLocalizedString(@"Warning", nil);
        NSString *dataSuccesful=NSLocalizedString(@"Data Download Succesfully", nil);
        NSString *okay=NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil);


        UIAlertView *alertViewDownload = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:warning
                                                            message:dataSuccesful
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:okay
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertViewDownload show];
        alertViewDownload.tag=2;


        flag=NO;
}


tempElement=@"";
```

}
}

Thank you for your interest, and i am sorry for my bad english.

Best Regards.

Comment: You should try to modify your webservice. It's not like you need all information rite away. Fetch the products as and when they are needed in batches.

Comment: Please! - If you can control the web service don't download 9000+ products at once. Use some paging mechanism to fetch only a partial set per request.

Comment: Include only relevant code. What line of code is it failing at? Shouldn't `data` be an `NSDictionary`? How many bytes is your JSON data? The count doesn't give much information as to size.

Comment: i got exception right here, -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    
    if([tempElement isEqualToString:@"string"]){
        
    
        temp=[temp stringByAppendingString:string];
        //NSLog(@"temp = %@",temp);
        
    }
}The string has out of memory i guess right?

Comment: and i am going to try to paging mechanism, i will got products info 1000 by 1000 from the webservice.thanks for your advice and interest

Comment: As you you said; i used paging mechanism, and i did 100 by 100 from the webservice and it worked very well and also i tried 500 by 500 and 200 by 200 but my app got crash .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Either don't download so much at once, or, if you have to, download and save the JSON to disk. Then use a JSON library that gives you a parser (like [this one](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)) and parse the JSON in parts.